# Scala Type Mismatch- Expecting Int Instead Of Generic

Tags: scala

I have some code that's supposed to flatten a nested List which looks something like this

```
def flattenList[A](list : List[A]) : List[A] = 
{
  def flattenIt(inList : List[A], outList : List[A]) : List[A] = inList match
  {
    case Nil => Nil
    case (h : List[A])::tail => flattenIt(h, outList):::flattenIt(h, outList)
    case h::tail => flattenIt(tail, outList(h)) //Here's where the error occurs
  }
  flattenIt(list, List())
}

val nestedList = List(1, List(2, 3, 4), 5, List(6, 7, 8), 9, 10)
println(flattenList(nestedList))
```

But I get a compile time error

```
[ERROR] C:\***\src\main\scala\com\***\FlattenList.scala:19: error: type mismatch;
[INFO]  found   : A
[INFO]  required: Int
[INFO]          case h::tail => flattenIt(tail, outList(h))
[INFO]                                                         ^
```

Now I have declared outList as `outList : List[A]`, so it should expect `A` and not `Int`.

Could someone tell me why the code is asking for an Int

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The problem is this line

```
case h::tail => flattenIt(tail, outList(h))
```

It should be this instead

```
case h::tail => flattenIt(tail, outList:::List(h))
```

This solves the error. Additionally

```
case (h : List[A])::tail => flattenIt(h, outList):::flattenIt(h, outList)
```

should be

```
case (h : List[A])::tail => flattenIt(tail, outList:::h)
```

and `case Nil => Nil` becomes `case Nil => outList`

So, `flattenList` becomes

```
def flattenList[A](list : List[A]) : List[A] = 
{
  def flattenIt(inList : List[A], outList : List[A]) : List[A] = inList match
  {
    case Nil => outList
    case (h : List[A])::tail => flattenIt(tail, outList:::h)
    case h::tail => flattenIt(tail, outList:::List(h))
  }
  flattenIt(list, List())
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In `outList(h)` you [apply](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/collection/immutable/List.html#apply(n:Int):A) `h` to `outlist`. But `h` is an element of type `A`, while `apply` of `List` expects an index, which has to be an `Int`.

Your type signatures also don't seem to match. You want to flatten a `List[A]` to a `List[A]`? That doesn't make any sense.

Comment: The input List can contain Lists as well as Ints as you can see in `val nestedList`

Comment: I invite you to try out `flattenList(List(List(1, 2), List(3))).head`. (once you got your code working)

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

```
def flatten[A](x: List[A]):List[_] = {
  x flatMap  {
  case n: List[A] => flatten(n)
  case e:A          => List(e)
  }
}
```

Try with `flatten(List(List(1, 1), 2, List(3, List(5, 8)))))` output will be 
`List(1,1, 2, 3, 5,8)`